# I want to set header title while using tab navigation in the stack -navigation but it is not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**This is my navigationfunction i even console but nothing **

```
  const tabScreen = createBottomTabNavigator({
            Tab1: { screen: Tab1 },
            Tab2: { screen: Tab2 },
            Tab3: { screen: Tab3 },
        },  
            {
                navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
                    const { routeName } = 
     navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
                    return {
                        headerTitle: 'Hassam'
                    }
                }
            } 
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Its almost fine you need to restart the metro bundler**